# How can I prove equality of lists by induction?

Tags: coq

I'm very new to Coq. Suppose under some hypothesis I want to prove `l1 = l2`, both of which are lists. I wonder what is a general strategy if I want to prove it inductively.

I don't know of any way to do induction on `l1` and `l2` at the same time. If I do induction first on `l1`, then I'll end up having to prove `l1 = l2` under hypothesis `t1 = l2`, where `t1` is tail of `l1`, which is obviously false.

Answer (score 3):

Usually it depends on what kind of hypothesis you have.
However, as a general principle, if you want to synchronise two lists when doing induction on one, you have to generalise over the other.

```
induction l in l' |- *.
```

or

```
revert l'.
induction l.
```

It might also be that you have some hypothesis on both `l` and `l'` on which you can do induction instead.
For instance, the `Forall2` predicate synchronises the two lists:

```
Inductive Forall2 (A B : Type) (R : A -> B -> Prop) : list A -> list B -> Prop :=
| Forall2_nil : Forall2 R [] []
| Forall2_cons : forall (x : A) (y : B) (l : list A) (l' : list B), R x y -> Forall2 R l l' -> Forall2 R (x :: l) (y :: l')
```

If you do induction on this, it will destruct both lists at the same time.